# How to make the Inventory Item Label (IN619200) to print one label per unit of each item received?

Tags: c#, acumatica, acumatica-kb

Out-of-box `Acumatica Inventory Item Label` report (`IN619200`) is designed to print multiple labels for the line item on the receipt only when the item is serialized.  We will be modifying report that will allow user to select a receipt number and have the system generate the number of labels based on the quantity received for each item regardless if they are serialized or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will be modifying out-of-box Inventory Label Report (IN619200), which would print each label per quantity received rather just one for all quantity for non-serialized stock item.

We need a user table and need to populate it with data.

```sql
CREATE TABLE UsrNumbers(Number INT PRIMARY KEY);
GO 
INSERT UsrNumbers 
SELECT TOP 1000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) FROM sys.all_columns;
```

Where `1000` could be max possible value for unit per item.

Now Create `DAC (Data Access Class)` for `UsrNumber` and publish customization so that `DAC` can be used in report.

```cs
using System;
using PX.Data;

namespace InventoryLabelReportExtPkg
{
    [Serializable]
    public class UsrNumbers : IBqlTable
    {
        #region Number
        [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Number")]
        public virtual int? Number { get; set; }
        public abstract class number : IBqlField { }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Now modify Inventory Label Report (IN619200) in Acumatica Report designer and include a relation as below in Schema Builder.

[image]

[Download Deployment Package](https://github.com/Acumatica/Acumatica-InventoryLabelReportPerQty/)

Comment: Very elegant solution, just used it for a different report. Thanks.

Comment: @Gabriel, you are most welcome. I am glad it was helpful.

Comment: Hi. I did the exact thing and it was working great as well. But, all of sudden I start getting error about 'UsrNumbers' table not found.

I can see that the table exists in database 
https://imgur.com/a/obsl8jX

but I can't find the same table in Schema Builder in Report Designer.
https://imgur.com/a/obsl8jX

I even tried adding a different table. But it didn't work.

Comment: @BikashLama, make sure you have created DAC representing SQL table and is published.