# Multiply record by number in report

Tags: acumatica

I have added a custom field 'Print Qty' in Purchase Receipt Document Details so that I can specify the number of Labels to print in Report based on the value.

[image]

And currently my report designer previews the labels like this:
[image]

Now, I want to multiple the label to the times of 'Print Qty' value for the same Inventory.

I looked over the Designer but couldn't find any place where I could put the formula to do so or write queries to pull up records in that way.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi. I did the exact thing and it was working great as well. But, all of sudden I start getting error about 'UsrNumbers' table not found.

I can see that the table exists in database 
https://imgur.com/a/obsl8jX

but I can't find the same table in Schema Builder in Report Designer.
https://imgur.com/a/obsl8jX

I even tried adding a different table. But it didn't work.

Comment: You need a DAC (data access class) for it and it has to be published on your site. Adding table to DB is not enough.

Comment: Hi! I have already had DAC. I still don't understand the reason but once I published the customization again, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

Same principle applies but answer linked by Gabriel in comments has a much better way to define the join relationship than what I suggested below:

[How to make the Inventory Item Label (IN619200) to print one label per unit of each item received?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47872258/how-to-make-the-inventory-item-label-in619200-to-print-one-label-per-unit-of-e/47872259#47872259)

---

UI Controls can't be added by formula, only hidden. The schema builder Relationships tab defines what is a Detail record. I suppose you have 1 label in the Detail section and that the Detail record is POReceiptLine. With that setup you'll get: 1 Label * number of POReceiptLine records. You can't get 1 label * formula/field value.

If Print Qty equals 10 and you want to have 10 labels printed for the same POReceiptLine, you would have to craft a query in the Schema Builder that returns 10 times the same POReceiptLine. This could be achieved by creating a new custom table that links to POReceiptLine. You could insert 10 records in that table that links to a single POReceiptLine. In the schema builder you add a Left join link between POReceiptLine and that custom table, when the report is rendered it will duplicate the labels because you duplicated the number of detail records.